# Which is best tool to monitor web applications?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, server, monitoring

Actually our client has N number of websites and many of the times if something went wrong like site down,loading slow or database error occured, in such cases we don't get immediate updates.

Would you please help to suggest any web monitoring tool which will do work for us and send SMS & Email notification immediately if any of the above case occurs?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: There are multiple companies that do this we use http://www.monitor.us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Basically you are looking for monitoring tools which will monitor all your resources like your web server, cup speed and database services and etc.

For monitoring i would recommend New Relic tool for this activity. Currently we are using the same tool to monitor our live websites details and accordingly revert traffics and other services with it.

As request, it also has functionality for sending notifications via email.